# how to use hibernate annotations OnetoOne in springMvc?

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm working with ``` spring MVC``Spring security ``` `hibernate`

I've created 2 tables in the database , this the schema:

```
create table user(
id  int(10),
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table compte(
id int(10),
login VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES user( id)
);
```

I'm developing a web application for users managements, the administrator add user's informations and submit (data from the first form is inserted into the `user`database)  and  then in an other jsp he adds the authentication data for this user and submit ( here data is inserted into the second database `compte` )

the  form  in the jsp page that inserts into `user`'s table is done  correctly  when it's not joined to any other table . 
But when I tried to use hibernate annotations in my application and join the two tables `user` and `compte` I have errors :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.package.domain.User.compte, referenced property unknown: com.package.domain.Compte.User
```

user.java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {


@Id
@Column(name="id")
private int id;
@Column(name="name")
private String name;
@Column(name="address")
private String address;

 @OneToOne(mappedBy="User", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  private Compte compte;
 //getters and setters
```

compte.java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPTE")
public class Compte {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "login")
private String login;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;


@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private User user;

 //getters and setters
```

I don't know how should I insert `compte`data into  the second table ? how it will recognize that the login and the password correspond to the user's id just inserted.

PS : i've created 2 tables in the database to use the second for authentication in `spring security` if my database design is incorrect please tell me :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to specify not a class name (`User`), but a property name (`user`) in the `mappedBy`

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Compte compte;
```

In my opinion It will be better to associate `Compte` to the `User` by an additional foreign key and I would like to have `login` and `password` in the `User` table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "f_id")
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "f_login")
  private String login;

  @Column(name = "f_password")
  private String password;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Compte compte;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "comptes")
public class Compte {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "f_id")
  private int id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user")
  private User user;

  @Column(name = "f_name")
  private String name;

}
```